# qTip2 and atlas ajax (or just general ajax partial refresh) causes orphaned qTips

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms, qtip2

Bit long winded but bear with me:

asp.net updatepanel enclosing form with many qTip2, some ajax based some not.

So if I hover a qTip2 immediately after causing postback (which fires async update and refresh) the javascript in qtip starts to fire and on return creates the qtip but either because the event originating element no longer exists the qip just stays open (display:block) and appears top left of the document (i guess some code tries to work out .position but the element no longer has any).

You can see the error here: http:// www.matclad.co.uk/brick-slip-blends.aspx

Try i.e. click a design then as soon as you have done so move over one to the left or right. The qTip will just stay there. You can also do it when adding bricks though that is more difficult to time

The code that is creating the qTip is:

//function trimmed for brevity

```
    var els = $('div.pallet li.item .photo > input, div.lower li.chosen-item .photo > input');
    els.click(function(){els.each(function(){$(this).qtip('destroy')});})

    $('div.pallet li.item .photo > input, div.lower li.chosen-item .photo > input')
    .each(function(){
                    var id = $(this).parent().attr('rel'); 
                    $(this).qtip({
                            content: {  text:'Loading...', 
                                        ajax: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
                                                dataType: 'json', 
                                                url: '/brick-slip-blends.aspx/GetDataForSlip',
                                                data: '{Id:' + id + '}', type: 'POST',
                                                beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings){
                                                                    return !Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack();
                                                },
                                                success: function(data, status){
                                                                    this.set('content.text', data.d);

                                                }, 
                                                complete: function(){} 
                                                } 
                            },
                            hide: { event: 'click mouseout' },
                            show: { delay: 500 }
                        });
                    });
    $('.qt').click(function(){$(this).qtip('destroy');});
    $('.qt').qtip();
```

note that in trying to work around this issue I am destroying other qtips in the selector on click but this is not fully working (though it has fixed it partially) and I have also been trying to do some stuff in the PageRequestManager methods (atlas ajax API)

What sort of strategy should I use to get round this issue? Possible ajax queuing issue? global switch to cancel the creation (in a function passed into qtip)?

Help please I have been struggling with this and any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have taken a brute force and destroyed the qtip - I noted in my own code I was just:

```
$('.qt').click(function(){$(this).qtip('destroy');});
```

which I just moved to the top destroy i.e.

```
var els = $('div.pallet li.item .photo > input, div.lower li.chosen-item .photo > input, .qt');
```

I was not iterating all other .qt and destroying them. HOWEVER...

I don't believe this fully resolves the issue and I will no doubt be back.